# Selenium WebDriverChromer:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Im trying to do a selenium test with ubuntu 20.04 windows desktop,
when I write

> > python3 testSelenium.py

I get

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "testSelenium.py", line 13, in 
> > driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
> > File "/home/romansito/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
> > self.service.start()
> > File "/home/romansito/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
> > self.assert_process_still_running()
> > File "/home/romansito/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
> > raise WebDriverException(
> > selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

chrome version:
google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 94.0.4606.81

Comment: What is "ubuntu 20.04 windows desktop"? Do you mean Ubuntu 20.04 running on WSL?

Comment: yes, the windows app